# How to persist strings as nvarchar ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: orm, servicestack

I want to store strings as Unicode string via ServiceStack.OrmLite (SqlServer).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can create database with code. After that you have to change data types manually.

Comment: how much you kept thinking about this?